# How to count only the working days between two dates?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following table called **vacations**, where the employee number is displayed along with the start and end date of their vacations:

| id_employe | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2020-12-24 | 2021-01-04 |

What I am looking for is to visualize the amount of vacation days that each employee had, but separating them by employee number, month, year and number of days; without taking into account non-business days (Saturdays, Sundays and holidays).

I have the following query, which manages to omit Saturday and Sunday from the posting:

```sql
SELECT id_employee, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Date) AS year, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Date) AS month, 
       SUM(WEEKDAY(`Date`) < 5) AS days 
FROM (SELECT v.id_employee, 
             DATE_ADD(v.start, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) AS Date 
FROM vacations v CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s 
WHERE DATE_ADD(v.start, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.end 
ORDER BY v.id_employee, v.start, s.seq ) t 
GROUP BY id_employee, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Date);
```

My question is, how could I in addition to skipping the weekends, also skip the holidays? I suppose that I should establish another table where the dates of those holidays are stored, but how could my * query * be adapted to perform the comparison?

If we consider that the employee **1001** took his vacations from **2020-12-24** to **2021-01-04** and we take Christmas and New Years as holidays, we should get the following result:

| id_employee | month | year | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 | 2020 | 5 |
| 1001 | 1 | 2021 | 1 |

Comment: What MariaDB version you're using? You can run `SELECT version();` to check?

Comment: @FanoFN 10.4.11-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created a table that stores the holiday dates, then you probably can do something like this:

```
SELECT id_employee, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Date) AS year, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Date) AS month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.holiday_date IS NULL THEN WEEKDAY(`Date`) < 5 END) AS days 
FROM (SELECT v.id_employee, 
             DATE_ADD(v.start, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) AS Date 
FROM vacations v CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s 
WHERE DATE_ADD(v.start, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.end 
ORDER BY v.id_employee, v.start, s.seq ) t 
LEFT JOIN holidays h ON t.date=h.holiday_date
GROUP BY id_employee, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Date);
```

Assuming that the `holidays` table structure would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE holidays (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
holiday_date DATE,
holiday_description VARCHAR(255));
```

Then `LEFT JOIN` it to your current query and change the `SUM()` slightly by adding `CASE` expression to check. If the `ON t.date=h.holiday_date` in the left join matches, there will be result of field `h.holiday_date`, otherwise it will be `NULL`, hence only the `CASE h.holiday_date WHEN IS NULL ..` will be considered.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9540f549f61ff805dda649cab45af338)

Adding this solution compatible with both MariaDB and MySQL version that supports [common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(SELECT id_employee, start, start lvdt, end FROM vacations 
    UNION ALL
 SELECT id_employee, start, lvdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, end FROM cte 
   WHERE lvdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <=end)

SELECT  id_employee,
        YEAR(v.lvdt) AS year, 
        MONTH(v.lvdt) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN h.holiday_date IS NULL THEN WEEKDAY(v.lvdt) < 5 END) AS days
  FROM cte v 
  LEFT JOIN holidays h
     ON v.lvdt=h.holiday_date
  GROUP BY id_employee,
        YEAR(v.lvdt), 
        MONTH(v.lvdt);
```

Comment: I was trying to use ```NOT IN``` AND ```NOT EXISTS```, but I knew there was a simpler solution for my question. Thank you very much!